# bottom of page cookie alert or warning

Tags: html, css

I would like to add a div at the bottom of my website like what you have with this site, warning users about cookie's. But have it disappear after 5-6 seconds. How would this be done?

Comment: do you want the div to stay fixed to bottom of the screen when scrolling or be at the end of the web page like a footer?

Comment: Yes stay fixed to the bottom

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="cookie-bar"></div>
</body>
```

In your CSS:

```
div .cookie-bar {
  overflow: hidden;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

In a JavaScript file:

```
setTimeout(fade_out, 5000);

function fade_out() {
  $("#cookie-bar").fadeOut().empty();
}
```

Comment: Is the above code correct?   the div works but does not disappear even when I change the  fade_out time

Comment: I figured it out by using @-webkit-keyframes  cssAnimation, no java needed